# Accuracy at 0 during inference with peft and Vision EncoderDecoderModel from huggingface

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface, peft, huggingface-hub, donut

I trained a DonUT model to perform document extraction from receipt, after the training I tested the accuracy and everything was fine so I pushed the tokenizer and the model to hub.

But when I call it from hub the model behave as if it was never trained, the results are not even coherent. This happens only with the peft finetuned model. I have done a full finetuning just before and everything is fine.

[Link to the source code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarmevaa/full-finetuning-of-donut-on-numeric-data/edit)